# PIL shows black image when attempting to view image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

The current goal of what I am writing is to download an image from S3, open it using Pillow, and show the image.  I am able to download the image fine; it can be viewed properly from my photos.  However, when I try to use the image with PIL, all of the pixel values are black.  It does however, retain the shape of the image, which leads me to know that the image is at least being read.  the code is shown below:

```
s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, key) # downloaded perfectly fine
img = Image.open(key)
img.show() # shows all black with the Images's dimensions
```

I know I can read from bytes, but that will give me a 1d array of all the bytes instead of the dimensions needed for an image.

Comment: Since you add the OpenCV flag, have you tried it with OpenCV? does it gives similar problem? what type of image is it (jpg, png, etc)? how was the image created?

Comment: @api55 I have.  I am able to read the image locally in that as well, but get the statement "Premature end of JPEG File".  When I run that in a server and that prints, it cannot accept any more http requests.  Image source is jpg that was initially downloaded from s3 as described.  However, my test image is a jpg converted from pdf.

Comment: So there is an error in the image... it could be when it was created (it has to end with 0xFFD9 ) or maybe when it is downloaded... for the second one, you can try to do some kind of checksum of it.... for the first one try creating the image locally using the same tool and pdf, and see if it gives the same error... if this happens maybe you need some other method to convert it...

Comment: @api55 I remember the byte string starting with \xff\xd8.  I thought that would make for a valid JPEG file.  I'll give it a shot and post the solution.

Comment: That is the correct start of a JPEG file. BTW, did you get any result from OpenCV or it crashed with that error, I think that is only a warning and still it get's you something...? [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35787338/888688), it is in PhP, but the answer suggest to write the end of jpeg bytes at the end... maybe you can load the bytes, add this 2 and then use imdecode from OpenCV or `image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))` with PIL