Opencv decode failing for user uploaded images
I am getting the decodedMat object as
Mat [ 00CV_8UC3, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x6000005f5800, dataAddr=0x0 ]
for most of the jpeg images which are uploaded by users via camera/gallery. This mat denotes that post decoding of the image via opencv, its returning a mat of 0*0(0 height and 0 width).
What might be the issue here? I have tried with a lot of variations of flags. like GRAYSCALE and other combinations, but getting the same issue for all. The source images are correct and theres no issue with those. Sharing a few sample images.
am using opencv version 3.1.0 in a java dropwizard service. What might be the issue. sharing a few sample images.
https://ibb.co/GVLYnN9
https://ibb.co/VSR5gyj
https://ibb.co/w7RgYX5

Sharing the sample image metadata of one of the image which is failing.
Colour Model: RGB
Depth: 8
Pixel Height: 1,280
Pixel Width: 685
Profile Name: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
Density Unit: 0
Progressive: 1
JFIF Version: 1.0.1
X Density: 1
Y Density: 1

I tried with different variations of flags exposed in opencv, but its failing for all types. Is there any additonal encoding which a mobile or any sort of camera does which opencv is unable to handle?
I want the image correctly loaded as a MAT object for further image processing like cropping and resizing, Since the mat object is empty post decoding, all further operations are failing as
/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp:139: error: (-10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function throwOnEror
This is my method.
private Mat decode(final byte[] image) {
     final MatOfByte imageMat = new MatOfByte(image);
     final Mat decodedMat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(imageMat, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | Imgcodecs.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
     nullSafeRelease(imageMat);
     return decodedMat;
}

denoting it cannot work with empty images.

"I tried with different variations of flags" -- that's a pointless waste of time. If it doesn't decode in the first place, the flags won't change anything. The problem is likely before you even call the decode function you show in your question. Since you didn't provide a proper [mcve], it's impossible to tell where exactly.

@DanMašek, before calling decode, there's nothing significant I am doing.
Just passing the image as a byte[], IOUtils.toByteArray(entity.getContent())
Can you please check the 3 sample images I have shared? any of those?
All these images are having the same issue.

No problem with those images. Validate that the size of the array matches the size of the file. Try to dump it to a file instead of doing the imdecode -- do the contents match?

Checked this, the contents are matching and so does the length. any other suggestions?
Its failing at the imdecode function , when am simple trying to convert it in a MatOfByte object, its working. post that, in the imdecode function am getting that 0*0 Mat. Any other suggestions @DanMašek

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438813/premature-end-of-jpeg-file
This is most likely related to this thread..Is there a opencv equivalent for this?

Dunno, sorry -- if I can't reproduce the issue, there's not much I can do. | BTW, is there a good reason why you're using something as old as version 3.1.0? That's rather ancient.

However, if imdecode fails, then imread reading the same file directly from disk should fail as well. You might need to write a separate program to test that. Both should be using the same code to decode the image data.

The issue was due to incorrect JPEG file ending. All JPEGS must end with FFD9 byte. but these are some faulty jpegs which other image softwares are able to handle and opencv is not. Added this manually and then deocded, which was working.
